# Can i use Play and Akka with Clojure?

Tags: clojure, playframework, akka

In general, is it possible to use Scala Frameworks with Clojure and vice versa?
I heard a lot of good things about Akka and Play but i like Clojure better than Scala.

Comment: yes, there is always java interop

Comment: One of the best things about Clojure is its idiomatic handling of concurrency. Using Clojure as a wrapper of some other concurrency system is like using Haskell as a wrapper of the C++ type system and avoiding Haskells types. What we have built in is fully integrated in the language, simpler to access, and the primary reason for using the lang in the first place. If you want Akka's way of handling concurrency, Clojure won't help you much, and if you want Clojure's way of doing concurrency, Akka won't help you much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It surely is possible. You can call clojure code from Java and vice versa. You can do the same with scala as well and though I have never tried it, I think you also can call Scala from clojure and vice versa.

But I cannot imagine how one would do that in a useful way? Clojure being data first vs. classes for Java and Scala being the main concept I don't see how one would use them on the same parity. 
Maybe writing a wrapper around the library from one side or the other so you can stay within one language for your business logic, that would seem useful.

OTOH, that I dont see it being useful, doesn't mean there is no use case for it.

Still, I would suggest doing a prototype with Scala and Akka for your problem and compare it to a prototype with clojure and maybe core.async and see what fits you better.

Answer (score 2):

There are interoperability issues between Java and Scala code. Essentially, you can use Java libraries from Scala without any problem, but using a Scala library from Java will have some limitations. Some features such as traits and implicits aren't part of the Java language, and they can be essential parts of libraries. I suspect that you'll run into the same issues you have with calling Scala code from Java if you end up picking Clojure.

All in all, if you're going to use the Play! Framework with Clojure, I'd recommend using the Java API instead of the Scala one. There is also a Java API for Akka.